# a:active not changing background colour

Tags: css

I'm basically testing CSS buttons to use in ul's as navigation, I can get the pseudo classes to do most things I want, but I can't seem to get the background colour to change!
It'll probably be one of those silly things that I should have seen, but perhaps someone else will see my mistake.

```
a:Active {
    /* General  */
    /* Size */
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background-position:0 2px;
    color:#F00;

    /* Stroke  */
    border: 1px solid hsla(0.0, 0.0%, 42.0%, 0.52);
    -moz-border-radius: 0px; /* FF1-3.6 */
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android <1.6 */
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */

    /*  Label  */
    font-family: "Lucida Grande","Verdana","Arial","sans-serif";
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:normal;
    display:block;

    /*  Shadow & Inner Shadow */
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 2px hsla(0.0, 0.0%, 65.9%, 0.58);

    /*  Opacity  */
    opacity: 1.000;
}
```

Comment: You are not setting the background anywhere in the code you provided. And `a:Active` should be `a:active`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mLUjgQhz
Here's the full thing,

Comment: Can anyone help me?
I'm sure it's something idiotic im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `background-color` in your CSS! You just have `color`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that before - Even background-color:# doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Where's your background color at?

I guess your error is `color: #F00;` which should be `background-color: #F00;` and also what **sandeep** said.

Comment: That doesnt work either, and it's worth noting that the other parts of the markup do, like the background position!